# Splitting text in a cell everytime it finds a special character, in vba, and pasting values, starting at a specific cell, and every row below that

Tags: excel, vba, split

I have this string of text, it could be larger, this is an example:

2.01g 10k gold wedding band~15xps3 games~14.01 14k diamond solitaire with .30pt diamond~2ps3 games~14dvds

Every time it sees the "~", for example, I want it to paste values in cell g34. If there is more than one row, I want it to continue pasting the values into g35, g36, g37 and so on until the list is exhausted.

I want this to be done in VBA so I can attach it to a button. I do not want to do it by text to columns.

The result should look like this:

```
2.01g 10k gold wedding band
15xps3 games
14.01 14k diamond solitaire with .30pt diamond
2ps3 games 
14dvds
```

Any help GREATLY appreciated...I can find similar solutions, but most want to paste it into new columns.

Comment: Hey Welcome to Stackoverflow, check out the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to perfect your question and make it more appealing ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub parse()
    Dim s As String
    s = "2.01g 10k gold wedding band~15xps3 games~14.01 14k diamond solitaire with .30pt diamond~2ps3 games~14dvds"
    arr = Split(s, "~")
    Range("G34").Resize(UBound(arr) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(arr)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a top! Thank you!